# ctrl + k + c or ctrl + k, ctrl + c not working with JavaScript File on VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have another simple problem. So, I try to create multiline comment on JavaScript with ctrl + k + c or ctrl + k, ctrl + c, but it's not working. I using the same shortcut for HTML and CSS files, it's working. Why this is happened? Please help me guys, this is a bit annoying, because I used to comment with this shortcut. For single line (ctrl + /) comment it's working well, the problem is for multiline comment...

Comment: `shift+alt+a` is `toggle block comment`.

Comment: You Can Just Use ` (The One Next To 1 On Most Keyboards) this key for writing multiline comments

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.